# How to turn off Jackson2HttpMessageConverter

Tags: java, spring, jackson

I'm writing simple REST API in spring connecting to other API. I have to send xml to external api:

```
doc = new Document();

Element email = new Element("email");
email.setText(getProfileById(idProfile).getEmail());

Element contributor = new Element("contributor");
contributor.setNamespace(Namespace.NO_NAMESPACE);
contributor.setContent(email);

Element entry = new Element("entry");
entry.setNamespace(Namespace.getNamespace("http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom"));
entry.setContent(contributor);

doc.addContent(entry);
```

To send request to this API I use this code:

```
HttpEntity<Document> request = new HttpEntity<>(doc, headers);
ResponseEntity<Feed> response = restTemplate.exchange(
                URL + "/communities/service/atom/community/members?communityUuid=" + idCommunity,
                HttpMethod.POST,
                request,
                Feed.class);
```

If I try to do this, I've got this kind of error:

> 2018-11-28 11:42:30.556  WARN 12152 --- [nio-8080-exec-2]
>   .c.j.MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter : Failed to evaluate Jackson
>   deserialization for type [[simple type, class
>   com.rometools.rome.feed.atom.Feed]]:
>   com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: Conflicting
>   setter definitions for property "content":
>   org.jdom2.Element#setContent(1 params) vs
>   org.jdom2.Element#setContent(1 params)
>   org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotWritableException:
>   Could not write JSON: Infinite recursion (StackOverflowError);

Any ideas what I'm making wrong? I set headers to application/atom+xml. Feed is class from Rome Tools. Thanks for answers.

Comment: Was my answer helpful? Please let me know, I can help more if it was not

Answer (score 0):

The `Feed` class from library seems to have two conflicting setters with both 1 parameters for `"content"` field (inherited from [`Element`](http://www.jdom.org/docs/apidocs/org/jdom2/Element.html) class), thus Jackson is failing to do deserialization of the class since it cannot determine which one to use. Can you try to create your own `CustFeed` class as following;

```
class CustFeed extends Feed {

    @JsonProperty("content")
    public void setContentCustom(Content content) {
        super.setContent(content);
    }
}
```

Then pass this one to `restTemplate`;

```
ResponseEntity<CustFeed> response = restTemplate.exchange(.., CustFeed.class);
```

Comment: Ok, but why in other function it works? I have problem only here :(

Comment: @Gnex which is the part where it works? I did not get that from the question sorry >_>

Comment: I have multiple functions using same HttpEntity and ResponseEntity with Feed class and they works. Difference is that function in question is using jdom2 to build xml. Because of that It doesn't work. I don't have any idea how to repair that.

Comment: I am not into the feed & jdom stuff, but it might be the other responses not having the `content` value might be the answer, since there is nothing to deserialize, jackson does not care about conflicting setters? I am not sure how you are using in other places, but here the deserialization is failing; `Failed to evaluate Jackson deserialization`

Comment: Ups, sorry :( You're answer didn't help. I don't have any idea how to do it. Anyway thanks for trying to help! Have a nice day :)

Comment: @Gnex if you can supply more info about what exactly do you want, and what did not work with my answer, I can help, no need to leave question unresolved!